# jquery currying

Tags: javascript, jquery

Please see
[Accessing Parameters *and* Events in function from jQuery Event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1798828/accessing-parameters-and-events-in-function-from-jquery-event)

How can I change this code so `$(this)` acts like `$(this)` in a click event instead of returning the complete html document?

```
 <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Expires" content="Fri, Jan 01 1900 00:00:00 GMT">
<meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache">
<meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="no-cache">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
<meta http-equiv="content-language" content="en">
<meta name="author" content="">
<meta http-equiv="Reply-to" content="@.com">
<meta name="generator" content="PhpED 5.2">
<meta name="description" content="">
<meta name="keywords" content="">
<meta name="creation-date" content="09/20/2007">
<meta name="revisit-after" content="15 days">
<title>Untitled</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="my.css">
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function functionToCall(clickedItem) {
  return function (ev) {
    // both accessible here
    alert(ev.type);
    console.debug(clickedItem);
    alert(clickedItem.attr('id'));
  }
}


$(document).ready(function() {
   $("a").live("click", functionToCall($(this)));
 });
</script>
</head>
<body>
  <a href='#' id="test">Test</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Refactor it like this:

```
function functionToCall(ev) {  // ev -> event is passed by jQuery by default
    var clickedItem = this;    // this refers to the element that is clicked
    // both accessible here 
    alert(ev.type); 
    //console.debug(clickedItem);  // this may not work in all browsers. see my fiddle for a failsafe.

    // failsafe: check if console exists
    if(window.console && window.console.debug) { console.debug(clickedItem);  }
    alert($(clickedItem).attr('id'));   // $() to get jQuery object
} 

 $(document).ready(function() { 
   $("a").live("click", functionToCall);   // just need to pass a function reference
 });
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/mrchief/ZYGVz/1/

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
$("a").each(function(){
  $(this).live("click",functionToCall($(this)));
})
```

Comment: `each` is not needed. jQuery will bind the click event to all `a` elements when you say `$('a').live(...)`.

Comment: One of us misunderstands the question